# Normalizations: dividing by maximum

Tags: normalization, extreme-value

I'd like to know what are the reasons and benefits of dividing all the values of a dataset by the maximum of the dataset. Are they referred by authors? This normalization is well known in gene expression, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, your features need to be **scaled** (normalized, standardized, etc.) before processed by most Machine Learning techniques.

There are several for which this is required. A couple are:

- Many distance-based models (e.g. k-NN, k-means) might treat features with a higher range of values with more importance.
- Neural Networks trained with Gradient Descent converge faster if their input features are scaled to the same range [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5E2X1JdHAU&list=PLLssT5z_DsK-h9vYZkQkYNWcItqhlRJLN&index=20&ab_channel=ArtificialIntelligence-AllinOne). Additionally, it helps keep their activations and subsequently their weights small.

There are however algorithms (e.g. tree-based ones) that don't gain any benefit from normalizing your features. In any case, though, it's a good practice to do so.

Comment: Very good reasons, in fact! Precisely because I'm using clustering techniques based on k-NN. In my paper, I have to justify why I'm using the max normalization and your answer gives me a very good starting point!